# laravel how to call a function with multiple updated value in the blade script

Tags: jquery

I am working on a laravel project, I have 2 inputs from UI, if one of 2 inputs changed or both of two inputs changed, I need to call a function with the changed inputs, now I can just call the function with single changed input, can you please help me to modify to call the function with 2 changed values immediately? Many Thanks!
here is the script:

```
        var filter_funder;
        var filter_date;
        $('select[id=filter_funder]').on('change', function() {
                        filter_funder = $(this).val();
                        call Function ()
                        });
        $('input[id=filter_date]').on('change', function() {
                        filter_date = $(this).val();
                        call Function ()
                        });
```

Comment: Your question is asking about jQuery code as it seems. Update your tags to get to the correct audience for this question.

Answer (score 2):

If you use a common class name (e.g., `select_class`) for both inputs:

```js
var filter_value;
$('.select_class').on('change', function() {
    `filter_value = $(this).val();
    call Function ()
});
```